# One Management Reporter server for two Dynamics AX instances

Tags: sql-server, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, windows-server

In our company we have two **Dynamics AX 2012R3** instances on one server. And also **SQL Server 2014** with DEV and TEST instanses. 
And I need to install Management Reporter Server which should work with both AX instances in the same time. But unfortunately in MR2012 config I cannot set more than one database.

So the qeustion is what should I do?

1) Should I install two instances of Management Reporter Service 2012? If yes, How can I do that?

2) Config somehow MR2012 service to point to two different dabases in the same time?

3) Maybe there is a common solution for this problem?

Please help.

PS: My qeustion is really similar to [this one](https://community.dynamics.com/gp/f/32/t/111351) , but the answers did not help me a lot.

Comment: This may help you https://sdhruva.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/install-multiple-instances-of-reporting-services-on-the-same-computer-for-use-with-microsoft-dynamics-ax-ax-2012/

Comment: Installation/configuration questions are not a good fit for the [topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of Stack Overflow. Try [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or the [Management Reporter forum](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33?pi53287=0&category=Management%20Reporter) of the Dynamics AX Community.